# How to get an option of a multiple select object to be selected when mouse moves over that option

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

How to set index of a multiple select object to be selected when mouse moves over that index's option. for example in the next `html` code, when mouse move over <kbd>option 1</kbd>, it will be selected. I want to do it all in JavaScript without editing the `html` code.

```
<select size="6" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="1">option 1</option>
        <option value="2">option 2</option>
        <option value="3">option 3</option>
        <option value="4">option 4</option>
        <option value="5">option 5</option>
        <option value="6">option 6</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is that explorer does not fire any events for the options tag, nor does it allow us to get its coordinates or dimensions so i think that the only thing left to do is trick the browser a little:

1. Get the [select] object using its ID.
2. Next, get the first [option] object (for some reason not all of the
   children of the select object are options... i guess some are text
   nodes because we use white space to indent the HTML, so i'm using the
   second child (options[1]) in order to obtain a reference to the
   first [option] element.
3. Create a dummy div element which will be used as a hidden canvas.
4. Set the div to absolute position & visibility hidden so it won't we
   displayed and won't effect the content.
5. Set the div's height to the size specified in the [option] tag
   font-size style (this is the trick, i'm trying to calculate the
   height of the [option] element by its font-size. sometimes this
   value is specified in points (e.g. 10pt) so i'm creating a div with
   exactly the same value for its height and asking the browser to give
   the height back to me in pixels.  Once i have the height of the
   [option] element, the rest is trivial.
6. subtract the top most position of the select from the y coordinate
   of the mouse and divide by the height of the [option] element.  This
   will give us the element on which the mouse is currently positioned
   (mouse top position - select top position converts from screen
   coordinates to the select box coordinates and dividing by the height
   of the [option] element gives us the current [option].
7. Take the number of the current [option] and use it as the value for
   selectedIndex.

Code:

```
    function ieElementFromPoint( e )
    {
        var select  = document.getElementById( "mySelect" );
        var options = select.childNodes;
        var d = document.createElement( "DIV" );
        d.style.position = "absolute";
        d.style.visibility = "hidden";
        d.style.height = options[ 1 ].currentStyle.fontSize;
        document.body.appendChild( d );
        select.selectedIndex = ( Math.round( ( ( e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop ) - select.offsetTop ) / d.offsetHeight ) );
     }
```

For the rest of the browsers the treatment is much simpler:

```
var old = null;

function select( e )
{
    if ( document.all )
    {
        ieElementFromPoint( e );
    }
    else
    {
        var option = e.target;

        if ( option.tagName == "OPTION" )
        {
            if ( old != null )
            {
                old.selected = false;
            }

            old = option;
            option.selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to give the [select] the proper id (id="mySelect") & add onmousemove="select( event )" on the [select] as well.
This worked for me on: Chrome, FireFox (3.6), Explorer 8, Explorer 6 (emulated), Opera & Safari.

Remember to remove the test DIV from the document when we're done with it, otherwise there will be a bunch of unused DIVs in the DOM, so at the end of ieElementFromPoint() add:

document.body.removeChild( d );

Hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery:

```
$("option").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).prop("selected",true);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you like to give the select element an id of "mySelect"

```
<select size="6" multiple="multiple" id ="mySelect">
                  ...
</select>
```

With plain javascript, it would be implemented like this:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

var element = document.getElementById("mySelect");
var options = element.options;
for(var i = 0; i<options.length; i++){
    options.item(i).onmouseover = function(e){
        e.target.parentNode.selectedIndex = e.target.value-1;
    };
}

</script>
```

Comment: thanks a lot but this is not working on IE9. it works on firefox, chrome and safari.

Comment: After some time searching, I've discovered that IE (6-8 at least) doesn't trigger mouseover events for <select> and <option>. Maybe I am wrong. Anyways, you could always go with jQuery...